# Does HTTPPost get information before or after data is sent server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, passwords

I want to try and hash a password using .NET MVC, however I don't want to send a password in plain text over the HTTP protocol.

I'm thinking of using a hashing method in the controller using the HTTP Post attribute and FormCollection class but as this is in the controller class I'm not sure if it's a 100% secure.

When I use the HTTP Post protocol in the hashing algorithm will I be getting the submitted data before it's sent to the server or before?

Comment: The server is the correct place to do the hashing. Just make sure you are using TLS (https://...)

Comment: Hasing the password before sending it only hides the password. Replaying it is still possible.. as mentioned before, use HTTPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I don't want to send a password in plaintext"

...in that case, ensure that all requests to your site use HTTPS. That will encrypt the whole connection. So your code can send the password as plain text, but HTTPS will ensure that it isn't actually transmitted like that. It will also handle decryption at the server end before the data is passed to your application.

If you send the password hashed but without encrypting the transmission, then someone could intercept it, and then gain access to your application by simply sending their own request containing the same hash value, and of course the server would consider it to be the correct password.

Answer (score 2):

> Does HTTPPost get information before or after data is sent server-side?
>
> When I use the HTTP Post protocol in the hashing algorithm will I be getting the submitted data before it's sent to the server or before?

The code you write in your controllers runs on the server. Before data ends up on the server, it will be transmitted from the client to the server. If you don't use HTTPS, it will be readable by anyone with access to the client, the server or the network in between.

So: use HTTPS. Don't invent your own hashing mechanism because it will have flaws, as explained in the comments and other answer.